# colorbox sending to the wrong url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, colorbox

I have multiple colorbox in one page.

those colorbox's links are generated with javascript.

Now every time a new link that opens a colorbox get generated any clicked link associated with colorbox will go to that new link's url.

this is how i declared the colorbox:

```
$('.ajax').colorbox();
```

the href in the link are correct but still send to the last generated link's href.

Thanks in advance.

Edit :
this is the code how i add some links:

```
$('.albums').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    parent_id           = $(this).parents().eq(2)[0].id;
    parent_header       = $('#' + parent_id + ' header')[0].innerHTML;
    parent_section      = $('#' + parent_id + ' section')[0].innerHTML;
    parent_footer       = $('#' + parent_id + ' footer')[0].innerHTML;
    fragment            = $(this).attr('href').split('/')[$(this).attr('href').split('/').length - 1];
    parent              = $(this).parents().eq(2)[0].id;
    if(fragment.indexOf('_-_') !== -1)
        page = fragment.replace('_-_', '/');
    else
        page = fragment;
    old_data[parent_id] = {'header': parent_header, 'footer': parent_footer, 'section': parent_section, 'link': parent + '/' + page};
    $.post('files/get_page', { page: old_data[parent_id]['link'] }, function(data){
        ret     = JSON.parse(data);
        a       = $('<a>').addClass('reset_link').attr('href', '#').append('Back To Albums');
        a.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            this_parent_id      = $(this).parents().eq(1)[0].id;
            $('#' + this_parent_id + ' header').html(old_data[this_parent_id]['header']);
            $('#' + this_parent_id + ' section').html(old_data[this_parent_id]['section']);
            $('#' + this_parent_id + ' footer').html(old_data[this_parent_id]['footer']);
        })
        $('#' + parent).children().eq(0).html(a);
        $('#' + parent).children().eq(0).append(ret.header);
        $('#' + parent).children().eq(1).html('');
        for(i in ret.body.images){
            href            = ret.body.href + ret.body.images[i].image_name;
            image_id        = ret.body.images[i].image_id;
            delete_div_id   = 'delete_image_' + image_id;
            body            = $('<div>').addClass('albums_div');
            delete_div      = $('<div>').addClass('delete').append('&#10006; Supprimer').attr('id', image_id);
            a               = $('<a>').addClass('lightbox').attr('href', href);
            a.attr('onclick', 'return false;');
            a.append('&#9673; ' + ret.body.images[i].image_name);
            delete_div.click(function(){
                id          = delete_div_id;
                id_array    = id.split('_');
                $.post('files/delete', { id: image_id, del: id_array[1] }, function(data){
                    $(body).remove();
                });
            });
            body.append(a);
            body.append(delete_div);
            $('#' + parent).children().eq(1).append(body);
            $('.lightbox').colorbox({rel: 'group1'});
        }

        footer  = $('<a>').addClass(ret.footer['attr'].class).attr('id', ret.footer['attr'].id).attr('href', ret.footer['href']);
        footer.append(ret.footer['text']);
        footer.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.colorbox({href: ret.footer['href']});
        });
        $('#' + parent).children().eq(2).html(footer);
    });
});
```

NOTE: the code generates the right links with the correct href but the problem in the colorbox it self. and I knew this because i did this:

i assigned a live click event to the links with the colorbox like this:

```
$(".upload_file").live('click', function(){
    console.log($(this)[0].href);
});
```

and the href printed to the console's the right one but the page that was displayed in the colorbox is wrong.

Edit 2 adding the HTML:

**the page before the javascript changing the code:**

```
<section id="reference">
    <header class="inner_header"><h3>R&#201;F&#201;RENCE PAGE SECTION</h3></header>
    <section>
        <h4>Choose an album :</h4>
        <div class="albums_div">
            <a href="res_yass" onClick="return false;" class="albums">&#9733; R&#233;sidence YASSINE</a>
            <div class="delete" id="delete_album_1">&#10006; Supprimer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="albums_div">
            <a href="res_nesr" onClick="return false;" class="albums">&#9733; R&#233;sidence NESRINE</a>
            <div class="delete" id="delete_album_2">&#10006; Supprimer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="albums_div">
            <a href="azerty" onClick="return false;" class="albums">&#9733; Azerty</a>
            <div class="delete" id="delete_album_8">&#10006; Supprimer</div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="inner_footer"><a href="files/add/reference" class="add_album ajax" id="reference">Add an album</a></footer>
</section>
```

**the page after javascript change the code:**

```
<section id="reference">
    <header class="inner_header"><a class="reset_link" href="#">Back To Albums</a><h4>Azerty</h4></header>
    <section>
        <div class="albums_div">
            <a class="lightbox cboxElement" href="f352702127.jpg" onclick="return false;">◉ f352702127.jpg</a>
            <div class="delete" id="128">✖ Supprimer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="albums_div">
            <a class="lightbox cboxElement" href="f65564287.jpg" onclick="return false;">◉ f65564287.jpg</a>
            <div class="delete" id="129">✖ Supprimer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="albums_div">
            <a class="lightbox cboxElement" href="f184021055.jpg" onclick="return false;">◉ f184021055.jpg</a>
            <div class="delete" id="130">✖ Supprimer</div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="inner_footer"><a class="upload_file ajax" id="azerty" href="uploader/get_form/reference/azerty">Upload une image</a></footer>
</section>
```

Comment: need more information. like code or something

Comment: that will take a long time to prepare because it's integrated in an almost complete website the problem is that when the new link is generated the colorbox get the href of that link every time any other link is clicked. it shouldn't do that but it does.

Comment: here some code hope it clarify what's my problem here.

Comment: @RicardoLohmann just corrected the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, the problem wasn't with the colorbox i just chenge the code from this:

```
$('.albums').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    parent_id           = $(this).parents().eq(2)[0].id;
    parent_header       = $('#' + parent_id + ' header')[0].innerHTML;
    parent_section      = $('#' + parent_id + ' section')[0].innerHTML;
    parent_footer       = $('#' + parent_id + ' footer')[0].innerHTML;
    fragment            = $(this).attr('href').split('/')[$(this).attr('href').split('/').length - 1];
    parent              = $(this).parents().eq(2)[0].id;
    if(fragment.indexOf('_-_') !== -1)
        page = fragment.replace('_-_', '/');
    else
        page = fragment;
    old_data[parent_id] = {'header': parent_header, 'footer': parent_footer, 'section': parent_section, 'link': parent + '/' + page};
    $.post('files/get_page', { page: old_data[parent_id]['link'] }, function(data){
        ret     = JSON.parse(data);
        a       = $('<a>').addClass('reset_link').attr('href', '#').append('Back To Albums');
        a.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            this_parent_id      = $(this).parents().eq(1)[0].id;
            $('#' + this_parent_id + ' header').html(old_data[this_parent_id]['header']);
            $('#' + this_parent_id + ' section').html(old_data[this_parent_id]['section']);
            $('#' + this_parent_id + ' footer').html(old_data[this_parent_id]['footer']);
        })
        $('#' + parent).children().eq(0).html(a);
        $('#' + parent).children().eq(0).append(ret.header);
        $('#' + parent).children().eq(1).html('');
        for(i in ret.body.images){
            href            = ret.body.href + ret.body.images[i].image_name;
            image_id        = ret.body.images[i].image_id;
            delete_div_id   = 'delete_image_' + image_id;
            body            = $('<div>').addClass('albums_div');
            delete_div      = $('<div>').addClass('delete').append('&#10006; Supprimer').attr('id', image_id);
            a               = $('<a>').addClass('lightbox').attr('href', href);
            a.attr('onclick', 'return false;');
            a.append('&#9673; ' + ret.body.images[i].image_name);
            delete_div.click(function(){
                id          = delete_div_id;
                id_array    = id.split('_');
                $.post('files/delete', { id: image_id, del: id_array[1] }, function(data){
                    $(body).remove();
                });
            });
            body.append(a);
            body.append(delete_div);
            $('#' + parent).children().eq(1).append(body);
            $('.lightbox').colorbox({rel: 'group1'});
        }

        footer  = $('<a>').addClass(ret.footer['attr'].class).attr('id', ret.footer['attr'].id).attr('href', ret.footer['href']);
        footer.append(ret.footer['text']);
        footer.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $.colorbox({href: ret.footer['href']});
        });
        $('#' + parent).children().eq(2).html(footer);
    });
});
```

to this:

```
$('.albums').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    parent_id            = $(this).parents().eq(2)[0].id;
    parent_header        = $('#' + parent_id + ' header')[0].innerHTML;
    parent_section       = $('#' + parent_id + ' section')[0].innerHTML;
    parent_footer        = $('#' + parent_id + ' footer')[0].innerHTML;
    fragment             = $(this).attr('href').split('/')[$(this).attr('href').split('/').length - 1];
    parent               = $(this).parents().eq(2)[0].id;
    if(fragment.indexOf('_-_') !== -1)
        page = fragment.replace('_-_', '/');
    else
        page = fragment;
    old_data[parent_id]   = {'header': parent_header, 'footer': parent_footer, 'section': parent_section, 'link': parent + '/' + page};
    $.post('files/get_page', { page: old_data[parent_id]['link'] }, function(data){
        ret = JSON.parse(data);
        swap_content(ret);
    });
});
function swap_content(ret){
    a      = $('<a>').addClass('reset_link').attr('href', '#').append('Back To Albums');
    a.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        this_parent_id = $(this).parents().eq(1)[0].id;
        $('#' + this_parent_id + ' header').html(old_data[this_parent_id]['header']);
        $('#' + this_parent_id + ' section').html(old_data[this_parent_id]['section']);
        $('#' + this_parent_id + ' footer').html(old_data[this_parent_id]['footer']);
    })
    $('#' + parent).children().eq(0).html(a);
    $('#' + parent).children().eq(0).append(ret.header);
    $('#' + parent).children().eq(1).html('');
    for(i in ret.body.images){
        href            = ret.body.href + ret.body.images[i].image_name;
        image_id        = ret.body.images[i].image_id;
        delete_div_id   = 'delete_image_' + image_id;
        body            = $('<div>').addClass('albums_div');
        delete_div      = $('<div>').addClass('delete').append('&#10006; Supprimer').attr('id', image_id);
        a               = $('<a>').addClass('lightbox').attr('href', href);
        a.attr('onclick', 'return false;');
        a.append('&#9673; ' + ret.body.images[i].image_name);
        delete_div.click(function(){
            id          = delete_div_id;
            id_array    = id.split('_');
            $.post('files/delete', { id: image_id, del: id_array[1] }, function(data){
                $(body).remove();
            });
        });
        body.append(a);
        body.append(delete_div);
        $('#' + parent).children().eq(1).append(body);
        $('.lightbox').colorbox({rel: 'group1'});
    }

    footer = $('<a>').addClass(ret.footer['attr'].class).attr('id', ret.footer['attr'].id).attr('href', ret.footer['href']);
    footer.append(ret.footer['text']);
    footer.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $.colorbox({href: ret.footer['href']});
    });
    $('#' + parent).children().eq(2).html(footer);
}
```

**Explanation :**
the first code i had the creation of the elements happens globally so every time the code executes it overwrite the variables and i'm assigning the the colorbox to the click function here:

```
footer.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.colorbox({href: ret.footer['href']});
});
```

so every time the footer variable gets rewritten over that click gets reassigned to the new footer that's why colorbox sends the data to the wrong url so all i have to do is to make those variables local to a function in this case the swap_content() function now each footer is unique and therefore colorbox will send the data to the right url.
thanks for those who tried to answer.
hope this helps anyone.